# What is the simplest way to get the selected text of a combo box containing only text entries?

Tags: wpf, combobox, selecteditem, selectedvalue, selectedtext

My WPF ComboBox contains only text entries. The user will select one. **What is the simplest way to get the text of the selected ComboBoxItem?** Please answer in both C# and Visual Basic. Here is my ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox Name="cboPickOne">
    <ComboBoxItem>This</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>should be</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>easier!</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

By the way, I know the answer but it wasn't easy to find. I thought I'd post the question to help others. REVISION: I've learned a better answer. By adding SelectedValuePath="Content" as a ComboBox attribute I no longer need the ugly casting code. See Andy's answer below.

Comment: If you know the answer, feel free to post it as well and mark it as the accepted answer. No need for others to do the same research twice. ;-) And who knows, maybe someone can come up with a better solution based on your work...

Comment: Adding to that comment, you could've easily marked your question as community wiki.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In your XAML add `SelectedValuePath="Content"`

```
<ComboBox Name="cboPickOne" SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem>This</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>should be</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>easier!</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

This way when you use `.SelectedValue.ToString()` in the C# code it will just get the string value without all the extra junk:

```
stringValue = cboPickOne.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

Comment: As much as I'd like it to be that clean and simple, that alone doesn't work. SelectedValue returns a ComboBoxItem, not the string value I'm looking for. Placing ToString after SelectedValue returns this System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem:  followed by the selected text.

Comment: OK. I see you've added SelectedValuePath="Content" as an attribute to the ComboBox. That works! No ugly casting required. It's nice, clean and simple - just what I wanted. Thanks Andy!

Comment: You can also bind to SelectedValue.Content as the path, this decouples the behavior of ComboBox from the requirement of the binding target.

Answer (score 11):

Just to clarify Heinzi and Jim Brissom's answers here is the code in 
**Visual Basic**:

```
Dim text As String = DirectCast(cboPickOne.SelectedItem, ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString()
```

and **C#**:

```
string text = ((ComboBoxItem)cboPickOne.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

Thanks!

Comment: It depends though on whether you specify the items explicitly as ComboBoxItems or through bindings directly as strings. In the latter case `.Content` would throw an exception I think.

Answer (score 10):

I just did this.

```
string SelectedItem = MyComboBox.Text;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you already know the content of your ComboBoxItem are only going to be strings, just access the content as string:

```
string text = ((ComboBoxItem)cboPickOne.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you add items in ComboBox as

```
youComboBox.Items.Add("Data");
```

Then use this:

```
youComboBox.SelectedItem;
```

But if you add items by data binding, use this:

```
DataRowView vrow = (DataRowView)youComboBox.SelectedItem;
DataRow row = vrow.Row;
MessageBox.Show(row[1].ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `cboPickOne.Text` should give you the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = (string)((ComboBoxItem)cboPickOne.SelectedItem).Content;

Dim s = DirectCast(DirectCast(cboPickOne.SelectedItem, ComboBoxItem).Content, String)
```

Since we *know* that the content is a string, I prefer a cast over a `ToString()` method call.

Comment: What does `DirectCast(...)`do?