# Get wpf combobox selected value

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I get the selected value (eg `Option1`) as a `string` from my example below. I've tried loads of suggestions on Google but can't get the string.

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="selectOption" Text="Select Option" 
                 SelectionChanged="selectOption_SelectionChanged" 
                 SelectedValue="{Binding VMselectedOption, Mode=TwoWay}" >
    <ComboBoxItem Name="cbb1">Option1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="cbb2">Option2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="cbb3">Option3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

**codebehind:**

```
private void selectOption_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var selectedValue = selectOption.SelectedValue; 
}

//elsewhere in code
var test = viewModel.VMselectedOption;
```

Both selectedValue and test return the string "**System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Option1**" and not "**Option1**"

This should be really simple but I just cannot get this working or see what is wrong?

Comment: Similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721430/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-the-selected-text-of-a-combo-box-containing-only the top answer worked great for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You shouldn't insert the combobox items manually. Set them by using [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx).

Basically you should create a list of options (or objects representing options) and set them as `ItemsSource`, this way your `SelectedItem` will be exactly the option which is selected, not the automatically created wrapping `ComboboxItem`.

Comment: Yours is the only sane answer I've seen here.

Comment: @ooo: glad that it helped. Using `ItemsSource` is a good option, considering separation of content and presentation.

Answer (score 21):

You should set SelectedValuePath="Content".

```
<ComboBox x:Name="selectOption" Text="Select Option" 
                 SelectionChanged="selectOption_SelectionChanged" 
                 SelectedValue="{Binding VMselectedOption, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                 SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem Name="cbb1">Option1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="cbb2">Option2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="cbb3">Option3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: This is the best and easiest way. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
string Value="";
if(myComboBox.SelectedIndex>=0) 
  Value=((ComboBoxItem)myComboBox.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

Comment: It is better to check:  if (((ComboBoxItem)myComboBox.SelectedItem).Content != null). Because if you use IsSelected="True" for some element the Content will be null after initialization.

Answer (score 7):

Update your code to get the Content of comboboxItem.

```
var selectedValue = ((ComboBoxItem)selectOption.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

[ComboBoxItem.Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx) is of type Object, so you'll need to cast the item yourself.